# Hive connector from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, hive

I want to query a hive database table from node js. I searched in npm and found two packages - node-hive and thrift-hive, but problems with both as follows

1) node-hive: When I try to run using this, there are many missing dependencies finally didn't get the module 'thrift/transport'

2) thrift-hive: When I try to run using this, query is running forever and not even doing a timeout. I suspect that the libraries they used are for old versions of hive.

The version we are using for hive is  1.1.0-cdh5.4.1.

Is there anything I am missing or is there any proper hive connectors in npm. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah even in 2017, I am having a hard time finding a reliable/maintained NPM module for talking with Apache Hive. I think we may need to write our Hive connector in a different language, but even when I search for HiveQL I cannot find good descriptions have how to talk to Hive. Typical Java-land bullshit IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resolved that dependencies issue then you need to first install thrift module with 0.9.1 version.

So add `"thrift":"0.9.1"` in your package.json and run `npm install`.

After that you will not get `'thrift/transport'` module dependencies error. Furthermore, even I am curious to know about which npm is best suitable to connect to hive. I am using node version 0.12.7.

Comment: @arjunkori : another way to connect to hive client is through JDBC driver but I am not sure what other dependencies are required along with that you have to check jdbc for hive with node js